# MDX query - anything like an "IN" operator in slicing?

Tags: mdx

So, I'm still pretty new at MDX (I come from mssql), but this project requires that I talk to an MDX database. Thus, I inherited a query, which looks like this:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY
{
    [Measures].[Time Spent]
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY
{
    [Consultant].[Account Name].[Account Full Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Consultant].[Activity Full Name].[Activity Full Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Consultant].[Description].[Description].ALLMEMBERS * 
    [Consultant].[Engineer Full Name].[Engineer Full Name].ALLMEMBERS
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM  
( 
    SELECT 
    ( [Date].[Date].&[2013-09-03T00:00:00] : [Date].[Date].&[2013-10-19T00:00:00] ) ON COLUMNS,
    (
        [Consultant].[Engineer Full Name].&[PERSON], 
        [Consultant].[Account Full Name].&[ACCOUNT],
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [Data]
) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS;
```

Obviously the dates, PERSON and ACCOUNT are actually parameters being passed in from higher up in the system, but you get the idea, hopefully.

This query is working (thanks to a previous SO question being answered - thanks!) - I get back data, and it's the data I want. However, I just got a request to be able to return results from multiple Accounts. I'd really like to be able to just modify that query to say that the Account Full Name is [ACCOUNT] or [OTHER ACCOUNT] or [DIFFERENT OTHER ACCOUNT], but just appending the queries seems to be getting treated as an AND? Is there any way to perform an OR or an IN on those values? (That is, a subquery filtering by the engineer being one value, and the account name being one several.)

I realize the easier way as far as my time goes, would be to just run the above query n times and concatenate the *result set* together, but I think that would also be the *ugly* way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if CrossJoin function might work in your case (not suer what you need to achieve)
but you can give it a try [CROSSJOIN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144816.aspx)

Your subselect might be edited like this:

```
...
SELECT 
    ( [Date].[Date].&[2013-09-03T00:00:00] : [Date].[Date].&[2013-10-19T00:00:00] ) ON COLUMNS,
    {[Consultant].[Engineer Full Name].&[PERSON]} *
    {[Consultant].[Account Full Name].&[ACCOUNT], 
     [Consultant].[Account Full Name].&[OTHER ACCOUNT] , 
     [Consultant].[Account Full Name].&[DIFFERENT OTHER ACCOUNT]} ON ROWS
...
```

Comment: Awesome, that totally works for my purpose. Thanks! (Though for anyone else who stumbles on this later, you might want to fix your link - it has an "and" stuck to the end of it.)

Comment: Glad to help and link fixed! Thank you!